# about transaction

Tags: transactions

I requested for withdrawal an amount of 7.48 BTC from my coin bank wallet having address 1Eurieh......REXWr. on 22 Jan.
Today 24 Jan ,my bl. in coin bank wallet is zero, but this amount is missing in my receiving end " My Ether Wallet" having address 0xbE3........2293.
How can i check this transaction on blockchain ace this transaction..
Please help to trace this tranaction.

Kind regards.

Dave

Comment: you may have a look at blockchain.info. You can enter your tx ID, and see the status. Hope this helps, as otherwise the information is a bit a mix of bitcoin and ethereum. Maybe you can outline, from which wallet you sent. I am not aware that you can send bitcoins to an ethereum wallet...

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any instructions for the Coin Bank wallet but, what you need to trace a transaction is the transaction ID. Once you have that there are various websites, you can look it up on, like http://blockchain.info

I would try contacting Coin Bank to find out how to get the transaction ID and try to deal with it as a lost transaction. The truth is, your BTC may be lost. If the transaction is not yet confirmed then there may be hope, you could try RBF (replace-by-fee) and instead send the BTC back to yourself or, you could try and double spend with a higher fee before the original transaction is confirmed. Both of these possibilities will depend on what features Coin Bank have available; it may be possible for them to do this on their backend if you cannot do it yourself in the wallet?

Also, Bitcoin and Ether are not compatible. I feel bad for you. You cannot send Bitcoin to Ether; it will not work. By the sound of it, Coin Bank may not have any send to address checking because the address you are sending to does not even look like a Bitcoin address.

Comment: thanx for your suggestions. I wrote to Coin bank team and they told me, they have transferred my balance coin bank funds to my GB21 account.
Dave